# Error : The "defined" test only works with simple variables

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to display prices in a specific format with twig/symfony.
I would like to consider the null case (there is no price) but I get this Symfony error:

> The "defined" test only works with simple variables.

Here is my code in twig :

```
<td>{{ _self.formatRemuneration(remunerationValues.variable_monthly_remuneration|number_format(2, ',', ' ') ?? null) }}</td>
```

Without this `?? null` part it only works if a price exists in the database. I don't take the null case into account.

I also tried to move the filter (`|number_format(2, ',', ' ')`) inside the macro but I get errors or 0.00 values instead of nothing.

```
{% macro formatRemuneration(remuneration) %}
    {{ remuneration is not null ? 'profile.remuneration.formated'|trans({'remuneration': remuneration}, 'company_position') : '' }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Can you help me write this condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, I'm not sure why you are doing something called `formatRemuneration` and trying to apply the the filter `number_format` both at the same time.

If I were you I would move the filter inside your macro, in which you then could test for a `null` value when the price  isn't set and return whatever you want, e.g. `Not applicable`

To fix the error you would only need to evaluate the variable, not the whole line, see below. This is because the filter `number_format` return an object of the instance `Twig\Markup`

```
<td>{{ _self.formatRemuneration(remunerationValues.variable_monthly_remuneration ?? null) }}</td>
```

If you can't move the filter `number_format` for whatever reason, you would need to change the snippet to the following:

```
<td>{{ _self.formatRemuneration((remunerationValues.variable_monthly_remuneration ?? null)|number_format(2, ',', ' ')) }}</td>
```

Keep in mind `null` will get converted to `0.00`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to put this in my macro but I always get errors or 0.0$, when I would like nothing to show up. I just edited my question.

Comment: What version of twig are you using? Possible the paramter gets converted to an empty string. Change the condition to `remuneration| trim ? ...`